# Special characters shows as "??" in php sqlsrv query

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding

I'm running SQL server 2012. I'm connecting with `sqlsrv_connect();`

If I'm trying to execute query with special (CZECH) charakters from database I'm getting "?" instead of "š" or "ěéíšáčáýžůú atc."

Here is my php query:

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE email='".$mail."';" ;  
$get = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $get, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '$row['nickname']';
```

Here is example from database:

```
Nickname = Stráša
```

The reasult I get is: Str??a

If I try echo "ěšíáéíá"; It works perfectly fine.
My charset is set to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
```

Is there any way how to make it works?
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxx", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
```